# How to make api call with parms from an array continously

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I have an array with some values that should be passed as parameter to a api call.
I want to update data with results from the api call. And I want to call the api every 1 second with each value of the array.

example :

```js
const people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

people.forEach((person, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${person}/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // do stuff, eg : update UI
        console.log(data.name);
      })
  }, index * 1000);

});
```

Since I want to keep calling the api and keep updating data or UI, is wrapping the forEach() in a infinite loop a good idea, like this :

```
 while(true) {
          people.forEach((person, index) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                  fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${person}/`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        // do stuff, eg : update UI
                        console.log(data.name) ;
                      })
                    }, index * 1000);

              }) ;
            } ;
```

if it's a bad idea please mention why and suggest other methods to do it right.
Thanks in advance.

Bit more info :-
The api I want to use has a rate limit of 100 api calls per 5 seconds, So I will have to call it every 3 seconds to keep it real time without hitting the limit.

Each array element is different endponts so it needs to be iterated completely to keep the data as real time as possible.

this script is supposed to run 24/7 to update the data

the starwars api is just used as an example because that was the first one that came into my mind.

Comment: That's a really bad idea because the while loop iteration will not wait for the timeouts. You'll be scheduling thousands of timeouts per second that way. You can either use an outer interval so the loop runs every 5 seconds (quick but bad fix), or use staggered intervals.

Comment: can you please explain ?

Comment: I would suggest doing a `setInterval()` at the bare minimum instead of a while. Can your api be changed to accept any number of people instead of just one person at a time? how often does their data change?

Comment: Use your first snippet but call fetch() inside a `setInterval(..., people.length * 1000)` callback. That way the 1st fetch request will run after 1, 6, 11 seconds, the next after 2, 7, 12 seconds, etc.

Comment: @ChrisG Pardon me but can you please elaborate a bit more ? Also this is an script that's gonna run forever maybe.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to elaborate tbh, but just in case you missed it, I'm using [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: I mean a code example, I'm still not good with the setInterval/setTimeOut functions.

Comment: I meant like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zj19g6pk/

Comment: try the code `while(true) { setTimeout(() => console.log('hello world'), 5000); }` you will see that it is fine for 5 seconds, and then it blows up. that is because `setTimeout()` runs async to the main thread, you might be thinking of [await sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) but setInterval is a better solution for what you want

Comment: So that worked except there's a {{array.length}} seconds delay before starting the api call. Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Did you look at my fiddle? I moved the call to a function and I'm calling it in the initial loop specifically to prevent that delay.

Comment: commented before looking your fiddle. That one is perfect for me. Will take sometime to understand how that works, but Thanks for the answer

Comment: That api lets you request all the people at once (in one request) - via /people/ - that would be a lot more efficient than sending a separate request for each person.

Comment: @James Thanks for the info but I was using that as an example.

Comment: @ChrisG Your solution works like a charm. It would be great if you can post your fiddle as answer so I can mark it as most apt one. Also I was trying to figure out how that solution worked, what I understood is that the forEach loop exexuted and exited but while executing it triggered the setTimeouts, and when the setTimeouts ran it triggered the setIntervals. and all of those actually ran outside forEach loop but was able to access the variables because of closure. Am I right ?

Comment: Exactly right, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally provided by @Chris G

This one is working like a charm

```js
const people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function apiCall(person) {
      fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${person}/`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          // do stuff, eg : update UI
          console.log(data.name);
        });
        
}

people.forEach((person, index) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
        apiCall(person);
    
    setInterval(() => {
            apiCall(person);
    }, people.length * 1000);
    
  }, index * 1000);

});
```

Just because I took sometime to understand how the above code works, I'm gonna provide some detail below :

The forEach loop executed and exited but while executing it triggered the setTimeouts, and when the setTimeouts ran it triggered the setIntervals. And all of those actually ran outside forEach loop but was able to access the variables because of closure

Answer (score 1):

Something that you can do to get the desired behavior you want is using a `setInterval()` with an interval time of your `people` array's length.

```
const people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

setInterval(() => {
  people.forEach((person, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${person}/`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          // do stuff, eg : update UI
          console.log(data.name);
        })
     }, index * 1000);
  });
}, people.length * 1000);
```

But right now you are being extremely chatty with your server and I would suggest doing a batch get, where you get all of the users at once instead of individually (and that you can call more often to keep the ui as up to date as possible). I assume this is your api and you can add a new function if you so choose.

```
const people = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

setInterval(() => {
  people.forEach((person, index) => {
    fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/getList/`, {
         method: 'GET',
         body: JSON.stringify(people)
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // do stuff, eg : update UI
        console.log(data.name);
      })
  });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: the data that api returns is also getting updated in realtime, so I think I'll have to keep calling to get the updated data

Comment: @me.nkr That is what `setInterval` does here, as opposed to `setTimeout`

Comment: @me.nkr Chris is right, the function `setInterval()` is basically an infinite loop that you can set a delay on for each iteration

Comment: so what should be the interval ? and is it better than a infinte loop using while(true) ?

Comment: @me.nkr the interval would be `people.length * 1000`. so if you have 10 people it will wait 10 seconds before calling the first person again. if you have 5 people it will wait 5 seconds before calling that first person again. and it is a lot better because `while(true)` runs as fast as it can. it doesn't wait for the settimeout to do its thing